# Is it true that "more taint-absorbing items = less protection against taint"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, taint

In a campaign in which I play, our DM is using 'taint' rules. Seeking to protect myself against taint, I found about taint absorbing items. The SRD has this to say about them:

> Some natural substances absorb taint and thus protect those who are exposed to carry them. Examples include a pure jade rod the size of a human finger, a sheet of vellum prepared from a year-old lamb, an intricately carved piece of lightning-struck oak, or a silk sash. The GM can create other examples appropriate to the campaign as well. Regardless of the shape or substance of the item, taint-absorbing items cost 100 gp each.
>
> As an item absorbs taint, it darkens, softens, and gradually rots away over seven days. During that time, it absorbs all taint to which the carrier is exposed. Possessing multiple taint-absorbing items at the same time can protect a character for longer than seven days, but the benefit does not accumulate indefinitely, as shown on Table: Taint-Absorbing Items.

As the text says, the benefit does not accumulate indefinitely. Nor does it stack perfectly. The table shows that two taint-absorbing items protect someone not for 14 days, but for 12. The longest protection is given when one carries 4 items with them, resulting in a protection lasting 16 days. After that, more taint-absorbing items create a shorter and shorter protection, with 5 items lasting 15 days, 6 lasting 12- And 7 or more items will last you even shorter than 1 item would: Only one day.

My question:
**Am I misinterpreting this table?  Is it actually an acumulative effect, as in "One item absorbs for seven days, a second item adds 12 to that" etc.?**

Or, if not, what would be a possible in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: @Desolli [Please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Comment: Please note the [meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8448/4563) about the taint tag on this question, in particular @enkryptor who removed it.

Comment: @ObliviousSage See above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, make sure you're looking at the right rules. There are two versions of taint in 3.5: one in the srd and one in Heroes of Horror. They are extremely different, so make you know whch the DM is using.

That said: you are reading the table correctly. While the SRD does not explain the phenomenon, the way I've understood it is that if you are carrying that many items absorbing taint; it becomes a fact that you are carrying a lot of taint with you. It's basically the same reason why more than 2 magic rings generally does not work, and actually nullifies all of them: magic radiates, and interferes.

Comment: Trying to wear 3 rings doesn't nullify all of them, you just benefit from 2 rings and not the 3rd. (DMG p.214 or MIC p.218)

Comment: @topquark I see the wording you are referring to, and I find it vaguely interpretable at best. "It doesn't work". It does not say what doesn't work, or in what way specifically, as is usual in the DMG. I will edit the answer if you take gross offense at it, though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the taint-absorbing items attract the taint.
When there's just a few of them, they pull the local taint to themselves, leaving the carrier 'clean', but as you get more and more of them, they pull *more* taint from the environment, eventually creating a situation where they attract more and more taint that, to the degree that they saturate more quickly, leaving the carrier unprotected after a shorter period of time.

That does, of course, lead to a clever way to sabotage someone journeying into/through a tainted area.  Secretly give them a significant number of taint-absorbing items.  By the time they notice, their protection will be nearing its limits, and they will still be several days from safety.